# Register for Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-broadcast

So I've been trying to register [`Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED) inside my `AndroidManifest` without success.

```
        <application>
        ...
            <receiver android:name=".broadcastReceivers.DreamingReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STOPPED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DREAMING_STARTED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        ...
        </application>
```

Here's the definition of the receiver.

```
public class DreamingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("DreamingReceiver", "Intent: " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

When daydream actually starts, there's just no log from that BroadcastReceiver.

---

However, when I define the receiver in my `Activity`'s `onCreate` method like so:

```
        this.receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                Log.d("Activity Dreaming", "Intent: " + intent.getAction());
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED);

        this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
```

I do receive the log whenever my device is entering/leaving daydream.
Is there a reason why the `BroadcastReceiver` that I defined in my AndroidManifest doesn't catch the Intent ?

Apparently, this doesn't need any permission according the the [`Intent` reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED)

FYI, running on Android KitKat 4.4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately the actions `DREAMING_STARTED` and `DREAMING_STOPPED` are marked with the flag `FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY` as you can see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/dreams/DreamController.java#L63-L66):

```
private final Intent mDreamingStartedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
private final Intent mDreamingStoppedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
```

Quoting [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY):

> **public static final int FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY**
>   If set, when sending a broadcast only registered receivers will be
>   called -- no BroadcastReceiver components will be launched.

So you can't receive these intent with a `BroadcastReceiver` declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Your only option is to register dynamically the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks ! Perfect answer !